# Compare heap and tree/

Tags: data-structures, tree, heap

I'm a newbie in data structure.

So i asked myselft what is different between heap and tree?

I also see on many documents that heap is implemented by array, and tree is poniters. Is that right?

And when we need to use tree, or heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tree in computer science is an abstract data type representing a tree structure. A node of a root can consist of child nodes where each child node are also trees.

Note that not all trees are binary search trees. A binary search tree is a tree with 2 defining properties:

- Each node has at most 2 children
- The left child is less than the parent
- The right child is greater than the parent

Another special kind of tree is a heap. A heap is special because it has the following property:

- every node in the tree is always less than or equal to each child node.

Now how you choose to implement a tree is up to you. A tree can be implemented through pointers/references; a node stores a value and pointers/references to its children.

A tree can also be implemented as an array. The parent is at index 0. If there are at most `d` children, then the `i`th child of the parent at index `k` is at index `d*k+i`. All else equal, we want to work with arrays because arrays are extremely fast compared to traversing pointers.

However, a binary search tree is typically implemented using pointers. This is because of two reasons.

1. If this was an array, it would always have to allocate enough space for the worst case scenario. In other words, if your binary search tree is of height `h`, your array must be of size `O(2^h)`. This is bad, because your tree could only consist of `h` elements.
2. Deletion is also very time-consuming. If you delete the root node, then you must shift an entire subtree up to replace it. The reason we want to use a binary search tree in the first place was to guarantee `O(log n)` operations, which we won't get with an array.

A heap, on the hand, is typically implemented as an array because its tree is always completely balanced (each node has `d` children except possibly at the leaves) This means there is very little wasted space so we won't have to worry about 1). Moreover, deletion for heaps doesn't affect the structure of the tree drastically like binary search trees can, so 2) doesn't apply either.

Comment: A *d-ary heap* is typically implemented as an array. There are many other kinds of heaps, most of which do not lend themselves well to array implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Heap is a special case of Complete Binary Tree in which a particular node is either greater than both of its children or it is lesser than its children.

There are 2 kinds of Heaps:

Min heap: In this heap any given node would be lesser or equal to both of its children.
Max Heap: any given node would be greater than or equal to both of its children.

Applications:

Sorting: Provides best sorting complexity ie. nlogn and performs it in place ie. without using extra space.
Used to calculate Running Median.
Used to make Priority Queue.